# How to restrict parts of API to Admin users

Tags: spring

I have a Spring API where users have to register an account in order to access data from a database through the API. I want to restrict some functions to administrators only, e.g. being able to call a "deleteAll" method. How can I do this? Or should I be creating a separate API for all the administrator functions?

Comment: Can you please be more specific like when you say API, are you referring to rest API?

Comment: Also, when you want to restrict specific functions to adminstrator, then there is no need to create separate API for the same function, it doesn't make sense. I think you have to be more clear and precise about your problem, so we can easily understand the issue.

Comment: @vine Yeah it's a rest API. I think I've solved it by using a `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` on my functions

Comment: Good. Yup that is the spring way indeed.